# Lightning: Reset component to initial state

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

What is the way to reset all attributes to default values and rerender component like it's initial rendering ?

For example, there is data list with pagination and sorting. The requirement is to reset this dataList, sorting and pagination to original state/view (back to default  sorting and first page)

The target behavior is to rerender component to initial view/state (the same when the component is loaded/rendered for the first time)

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution can be:

1.Implement resettable lightning interface

```
<aura:interface description="Interface template">
    <aura:attribute name="toReset" type="boolean" default="false" description=""/>
</aura:interface>
```

2.Extends this interface

```
<aura:component extensible="true" implements="c:resetable">
```

3. Implement value change handler to reset values

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.toReset}" action="{!c.onReset}"/>
```

Whenever you change value of toReset attribute, related `c.onReset` handler executes to repopulate/reset other attributes and as result this will trigger component rerendering similar to initial state/view.

Let me know if you have other ideas. Thanks in advance.